# Proving independence of discrete random variables given that $p_{X,Y}(x,y)$ = $g(x)h(y)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-writing

Let $X$ and $Y$ be discrete random variables. Suppose $p_{X,Y}(x,y)$ = $g(x)h(y)$, for some functions $g$ and $h$. Prove that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

I believe I have started my proof correctly, but am not quite sure how to finish it. Here are my steps:

> Proof

First, suppose that $p_{X,Y}(x,y)$ = $g(x)h(y)$ for some functions $g$ and $h$.
Note that $p_X(x) = \Sigma_{y}p_{X,Y}(x,y)$ and $p_Y(y) = \Sigma_{x}p_{X,Y}(x,y)$. This gives us
that $p_X(x)p_Y(y) = \Sigma_{y}p_{X,Y}(x,y)\Sigma_{x}p_{X,Y}(x,y)$.

Now, using the fact that $p_{X,Y}(x,y)$ = $g(x)h(y)$ , we get:

$p_X(x)p_Y(y) = \Sigma_{y}g(x)h(y)\Sigma_{x}g(x)h(y)$

$= [g(x) \cdot \Sigma_{y}h(y)][h(y) \cdot \Sigma_{x}g(x)]$

$= [c_1g(x)][c_2h(y)]$, where $c_1 = \Sigma_{y}h(y)$ and $c_2 =\Sigma_{x}g(x)$

$= c_1c_2g(x)h(y)$

$= c_1c_2p_{X,Y}(x,y)$

Now, I am not sure how to prove that $c_1c_2 = 1$ in order to successfully show $p_{X,Y}(x,y) = p_X(x)p_Y(y)$.

Comment: integrate/sum both sides - both sums will equal 1, and thus $c1c2 = 1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that:
$$P(X \in \mathbb{R} \text{ and } Y\in \mathbb{R}) =  \sum_y \sum_x p_{X, Y}(x, y) = 1$$

So we have that:
$$c_1c_2 = \sum_y h(y) \sum_x g(x) = \sum_y \sum_x h(y)g(x) = \sum_y \sum_x p_{X, Y}(x, y) =1$$

Comment: Perfect, thank you!